# Having Automapper use services constructed by a Autofac with WebApi

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, automapper, autofac

I'm using WebAPI + Autofac + Automapper, with a repository for data access. I need to map a model to my domain entities, specifically, I need to convert an identity value to the actual entity. No big deal, right? I've done this in MVC with no problem. I will simplify what I am doing to expose the essentials.

```
public class EntityConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<int, T>
        where T : Entity
{
   public EntityConverter(IRepository<T> repository)
   {
       _repository = repository;
   }

   private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;

   public T Convert(ResolutionContext context)
   {
       _repository.Get((int) context.SourceValue);
   }
}
```

Repositories are registered with Autofac, and are managed as `InstancePerApiRequest` because of session/transaction management. So, I need to register my converter in that same scope:

```
 builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityConverter<>))
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

The Automapper config looks something like:

```
 var container = builder.Build(); // build the Autofac container and do what you will

 Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
      cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve); // nope nope nope
      // configure mappings
      cfg.CreateMap<int, TestEntity>().ConvertUsing<EntityConverter<TestEntity>>()
});
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

So here's the part that sucks. I am to understand Automapper requires the `ConstructServicesUsing` guy to be set before you build your config. If you set it later, it won't be used. The example above won't work because `container` is the root scope. If I try and resolve `EntityConverter<TestEntity>`, Autofac will complain that the requested type is registered for a different scope, and the one you're in ain't it. Makes sense, I want the scope created by WebApi.

Let me pause a sec and cover one fact about WebApi dependency injection (I don't really think this is Autofac-specific). WebApi creates an `IDependencyScope` for the request, and stashes it in the `HttpRequestMessage.Properties`. I can't get it back again unless I have access to that same `HttpRequestMessage` instance. My `AsInstancePerApiRequest` scoping on `IRepository` and my converter thus rely on that `IDependencyScope`.

So, that's really the meat and potatoes of the problem, and I really frustrated with this difference from MVC. You can't do

```
 cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService);
```

That's equivalent to using `container.Resolve`. I can't use

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.BeginScope().GetService
```

because A) that creates a new scope next to the one I actually want B) doesn't really let me clean up the new scope I created. Using Service Locator is a new way to have the same problem; I can't get to the scope WebApi is using. If my converter and its dependencies were single instance or instance per dependency, it wouldn't be a problem, but they aren't, so it is, and changing that would create lots more problems for me.

Now, I can create AutoMapper config with Autofac and register it as a single instance. I can even create per-request `IMappingEngine` instances. But that doesn't do me any good if the service constructor always uses that single delegate you register at the beginning, which has no access to the current scope. If I could change that delegate per each mapping engine instance, I might be in business. But I can't.

So what *can* I do?

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov Unfortunately, no. I think a minor version has come out since, but I haven't checked it out. I'll investigate then open a ticket with the project.

Comment: @HackedByChinese, I might be wrong, but I think this is going to be solved in ASP.NET vNext. Have you looked at the CTP?

Comment: This is a fundamental flaw with AutoMapper. It pushes you toward static configuration, but you really need your dependencies resolved per request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option, this time it's built-in, is to use the per-map options:

```
Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(dest, opt => opt.ConstructServicesUsing(type => Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(YourServiceTypeToConstruct))));
```

Don't bother with setting up the global IoC config in your mapping configuration.

Another option is to use your IoC tool to configure how to instantiate the MappingEngine:

```
public MappingEngine(
    IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider,
    IDictionary<TypePair, IObjectMapper> objectMapperCache,
    Func<Type, object> serviceCtor)
```

The first one is just Mapper.Configuration, the second should probably be a singleton, and the third you can fill in with the current nested container's resolution. This would simplify from having to call the Map overload every time.

Comment: Was that constructor for `serviceCtor` added (somewhat) recently, or did I somehow miss it? That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @HackedByChinese I am talking to Jimmy about this just now, I believe the above needs to up updated to use ConstructServicesUsing.  See here: https://twitter.com/jbogard/status/555088549356138496

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I have a class that implements ITypeConverter, which in turn accepts a DbContext, with both being constructed using Autofac.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when you don't have web for Request and trying to set this up in your autofac Module - all you have is a ContainerBuilder.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** Automapper was updated to support that feature. See @Jimmy Bogard 's answer

This solution could be not very nice, but it works. The solution relates to WebAPI 2, I'm not sure about previous versions.

In WebAPI 2 you can get current `IDependencyScope` from current `HttpRequestMessage` via `GetDependencyScope()` extension method. Current `HttpRequestMessage` is stored in the `Items` property of the current `HttpContext`. Knowing that your factory could look like:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(serviceTypeToConstruct =>
    {
        var httpRequestMessage = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
        var currentDependencyScope = httpRequestMessage.GetDependencyScope();
        return currentDependencyScope.GetService(serviceTypeToConstruct);
    });
    // configure mappings
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Well damn, that should work. I wish it were something with cleaner separation and no dependency on `HttpContext`, but in my case that should work. I don't know if it'll work on OWIN, and certainly not for self-hosted, but perhaps there is a similar technique for that environment. I'd rather AutoMapper change so that the resolver delegate can be injected into `IEngineMapper`. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Does not work. The httpRequestMessage variable is NULL.

Comment: @bugged87 It works for me. What version of Web API do you use? Is "MS_HttpRequestMessage" key is actual for you?

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 NuGet Package, version 5.2.0.

Comment: @bugged87 Could you provide with more info please. Are you sure you aren't running the factory delegate in Application_Start()? How do you host the app?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be suitable for you.. but here goes:

We recently did this.. for model binders in MVC. Our model binders (on GET requests) now use Ninject-managed Services to build models.

Basically, we inject a factory (using Ninject's Factories extension.. perhaps there is a similar one for Autofac) into an "AutomapperBootstrapper" class, which in turn creates Automapper mapping `Profile`'s and adds them to Automapper. Somewhat like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(_factory.CreateServiceViewModelMappingProfile());
    // etc..
});
```

The mappings `Profile`'s themselves use `MapFrom()`, which is evaluated each time a mapping occurs. Something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Service, ServiceViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Regions,
                opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom(x => getRegions()))

private IEnumerable<Region> getRegions() {
    return _factory.CreateTheService().GetRegions();
}
```

Each time the model binder is fired up, Ninject still wires up all dependencies for the request and it all filters down.

(For those interested, this setup basically lets us do this: `/Area/Controller/Action/12`, and our controller action method is this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Action(ServiceViewModel model) {
    // ...
}
```

).

Comment: This approach works well with MVC, since you can access MVC's lifetime scope for a request outside of the context of the actual request (all you need is access to the DependencyResolver). However, the problem remains when it comes to WebApi; we can't access WebApi's current lifetime scope outside of the request, and Automapper doesn't let me update the service constructor delegate after it has been configured.